# Remove stylesheets from layouts

Tags: layout, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two layouts, `layout1` and `layout2`. `Layout1` is the first one to load when a new user comes to my website, after creating the account and all he will be sent to `layout2`.
The problem that I have is that my `layout1` needs only 3 css files, and `layout2` need all of them besides one. How can I remove that one css file?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In `layout1`, where you need just 1 stylesheet, change this line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
```

to include a different stylesheet, like

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "layout1_style", media: "all" %>
```

And of course create `layout1_style.css`. If that is a very simple stylesheet without the need for less/sass trickery, you could put this stylesheet in the `public` folder, so it does not interfere with the rest of your styles.